# Basic Calendar App in Android (API 11 and above)

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I am trying to build a basic Calendar App in Android. I am a beginner and from my understanding of the information given at the android development site , we can build a Calendar App either by using CalendarView widget, use Calendar Provider or Calendar Intent. I am confused after going through all of these. Can anyone of you please give me a starting point to begin my development. Would be very helpful if u could clarify the difference between these 3 approaches ( an example would help) .Thanks!